# INDEX MATCH in VBA issuing a type mismatch error

Tags: excel, vba

Getting a type mismatch error on the below code. Intention is to return a boolean to a cell that is from comparing the results of 2 outputs from 2 different ranges. One range is just a direct range() function, the other is a result found from an INDEX MATCH. The MATCH function is giving the error but I can't seem to work out why.

There are 2 different options that i have tried below.

```
dim i as long, j as long  
Dim index As Variant
Dim compare As Variant
Dim bool As Boolean  
i = 11
Do While i < RAGlastRow + 1
    j = 41
    Do While j < 44
        RAGspreadsheet.Cells(i, j) = Application.IsError(Application.Match(RAGspreadsheet.Range("C" & i).Value, HistoryWS.Range("C11", "C" & lastRow), 0))
        j = j + 1
        index = Application.index(HistoryWS.Range(Cells(11, 7).Address, Cells(lastRow, 7).Address), Application.Match(RAGspreadsheet.Range("C" & i).Value, HistoryWS.Range("C11", "C" & lastRow), 0))
        compare = RAGspreadsheet.Range("H" & i)
        bool = index <> compare
        RAGspreadsheet.Cells(i, j) = bool
        j = j + 1
        RAGspreadsheet.Cells(i, j) = RAGspreadsheet.Range("I" & i) <> Application.index(HistoryWS.Range(Cells(11, 8).Address, Cells(lastRow, 8).Address), Application.Match(RAGspreadsheet.Range("C" & i).Value, HistoryWS.Range("C11", "C" & lastRow), 0))
        j = j + 1
    Loop
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

or

```
dim i as long, j as long
i = 11
Do While i < RAGlastRow + 1
    j = 41
    Do While j < 44
        RAGspreadsheet.Cells(i, j) = Application.IsError(Application.Match(RAGspreadsheet.Range("C" & i).Value, HistoryWS.Range("C11", "C" & lastRow), 0))
        j = j + 1
        RAGspreadsheet.Cells(i, j) = RAGspreadsheet.Range("H" & i) <> Application.index(HistoryWS.Range(Cells(11, 7).Address, Cells(lastRow, 7).Address), Application.Match(RAGspreadsheet.Range("C" & i).Value, HistoryWS.Range("C11", "C" & lastRow), 0))
        j = j + 1
        RAGspreadsheet.Cells(i, j) = RAGspreadsheet.Range("I" & i) <> Application.index(HistoryWS.Range(Cells(11, 8).Address, Cells(lastRow, 8).Address), Application.Match(RAGspreadsheet.Range("C" & i).Value, HistoryWS.Range("C11", "C" & lastRow), 0))
        j = j + 1
    Loop
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Its the MATCH part of the INDEX MATCH function that seems to be throwing the error.

Comment: Qualify all of your ranges.  `HistoryWS.Range()` needs to be carried through for `HistoryWS.Cells()`, etc.

Comment: @Cyril I'm not sure I quite understand. Could you provide a bit more detail? Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming the match fails. Does the first `IsError` line succeed?

Comment: I think HistoryWs.Range is not correct. I think you should use `HistoryWS.Range("C11:C" & lastRow)`

Comment: @BigBen Yes it does. If I take out the <> operator and the comparison bit before it, the whole INDEX MATCH works fine to pass straight into the cells.

Comment: And the result of Iserror is true, correct?

Comment: Depending on the value of the range on the left side of the comparison, you could get a type mismatch if you try to compare to an error on the right side of the comparison.

Comment: Have you ensured that you *are* matching?  The type mismatch typically occurs when you don't have a match (using `Application` should trap that, like you used the `IsError()`).  Have you tried with a specificly written string in your `Application.Match()`, copied verbatim from `HistoryWS`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explaining my comment.  This applies to ALL of your code, though I will focus on `index` for this explanation.

You wrote:

```
index = Application.index(HistoryWS.Range(Cells(11, 7).Address, Cells(lastRow, 7).Address), Application.Match(RAGspreadsheet.Range("C" & i).Value, HistoryWS.Range("C11", "C" & lastRow), 0))
```

You didn't qualify all of your `Cells()` through-out, and you're swapping back and forth between `Range("A1")` and `Cells(1,1)` which makes it hard to be consistent.  See:

```
index = Application.index(HistoryWS.Range(HistoryWS.Cells(11, 7), HistoryWS.Cells(lastRow, 7)), Application.Match(RAGspreadsheet.Cells(i, 3).Value, HistoryWS.Range(HistoryWS.Cells(11, 3), HistoryWS.Cells(lastRow, 3)), 0))
```

I also dropped the `.Address` from the ranges.

---

It may behoove you to use a `With` statement so it's easier to read:

```
With HistoryWS
    index = Application.index(.Range(.Cells(11, 7), .Cells(lastRow, 7)), Application.Match(RAGspreadsheet.Cells(i, 3).Value, .Range(.Cells(11, 3), .Cells(lastRow, 3)), 0))
End With
```

Note that the `.` are maintained so that `HistoryWS` is always qualifying the appropriate ranges.

Comment: While this is a good suggestion, it won't fix the type mismatch. Using the `.Address` is equivalent to doing `Range("$G$11", "$G$100")`, for example - and that's a perfectly valid range syntax. I'm guessing the *type mismatch* stems from different types on either side of the `<>` - i.e. an error on the right side, because the match fails.

Comment: @BigBen Very true point on the `.address`.  When i was re-writing to a consistent format, I dropped them to keep consistent, as I didn't carry that through.  I called out that I removed them as clarity.

Comment: Just realized I wrote "clarity" when I meant "transparency"... the comment is the clarity, while the post is just stating that I did remove them.